# Pages generated from controllers can be seen but not the views that i added into that folder

Tags: grails

This only happens in production. It works in dev perfectly.

All the pages under `Person` works perfectly. Except for the once that i added to the Person view folder separately.

```
create
show
list
edit
```

works correctly, But the new GSP files i added like `createPerson.gsp, editPerson.GSP` ends up in a 404.

Why does the files that i generated work and the once that i created separately not work ?

How can i solve this ?

EDIT

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
def createperson(){
    render controller: 'person' ,view: 'createperson' 
}
```

Comment: are there corresponding controller actions in place?

Comment: All the actions are under the `Person` controller. `create,
show,
list,
edit, createPerson, editPerson`

Comment: the controller action have to be named without the ".gsp" extension. to the class should look like this: `class PersonController { def show() {/*...*/}; def createPerson(){/*...*/} /*...*/ }`

Comment: Yes. I have done it like that.

Comment: in order to help you, a little more code would be useful. Im form of a github sample app or something like this...

Comment: I have added some code. That createperson() method is in the person controller.

Comment: The only issue is that it works in `Development` (locally) and not in production.

Comment: the camelCase could be the problem. Is it possible, that the production box runs an os, which is case sensitive (and dev box not)? Had exactly this problem some time ago.

Comment: Its all lower case. Production server is run on a linuxOS. and dev is on OSX

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
render controller: 'person', view: 'createperson'
```

There are 2 things wrong with that.  You can't specify a controller in the parameters to the `render` method.  Another since you said the file name is `createPerson.gsp` then the view name should be `createPerson`, not `createperson`.

You probably want something like this:

```
render view: 'createPerson'
```

However, if that is inside of an action named `createPerson`, the default view name will be `createPerson` so your controller action could just return a Map and the framework will select that view automatically, but calling `render view: 'createPerson'` is valid if that is really what you want to do.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check this.

Comment: No that didn't work too. It works in Dev, and not in production.

Comment: The render method definitely works in production as I have described above.  I am sorry that I wasn't able to help you.  Best of luck.